# select query with difference

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table called actions, with the following columns, I want to extract only the `ID_tracking` that have not done a certain action. I tried

```
SELECT id_tracking from table WHERE id_tracking NOT IN
( SELECT id_tracking FROM table where id_action = X ).
```

This method works, but it takes extremely long on a small table, and there will be tables with millions of rows so this is not a solution. How can this be done?

Sample data

```
ID_tracking  | ID_action
  1009           1
  1009           2
  1009           3
  1009           5
  1010           2
  1010           3
  1010           4
  1011           5
```

Comment: With that sample data, what is the expected result?

Comment: Using distinct will speed up your query plus consider using join instead of inner query when you are working with big data. See my answer with demo

Answer (score 0):

I often approach this type of problem using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT id_tracking 
FROM table t
GROUP BY id_tracking
HAVING SUM(id_action = x) = 0;
```

One issue with your query is that you'll get multiple rows for each `id_tracking` that meets the condition.

In practice, though, a very reasonable approach would be:

```
SELECT t.id_tracking 
FROM tracking t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM trackingaction ta
                  WHERE ta.id_tracking = t.id_tracking AND
                        ta.id_action = X
                 );
```

This uses two different tables, one where `id_tracking` is the unique key and one which is the table you describe.  For best results, you want an index on `trackingaction(id_tracking, id_action)`.

Comment: I tried to apply the first option, here is the exact query: SELECT  av.id_tracking, SUM(av.id_action) FROM  2_project_tracking_actions_values  av  GROUP BY av.id_tracking HAVING  SUM(av.id_action = 3) = 0,  but i got results that have the  SUM( av.action ) higher than 0.

Comment: @PepeleaRazvanIonut . . . If you have a question about adding up `id_action`, then ask another question.  This question is about returning `id_tracking` values that have no value of "3" for `id_action.

Answer (score 0):

Using distinct and join will make your query hell faster (when you get numerous results in `inner query`). I just used distinct and translated your not in to join. Try this

[**Demo At SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/785b20/12)

```
SELECT distinct yt.id_tracking 
FROM table1 yt
left join (SELECT distinct id_tracking as idt from table1 where id_action = 3) mt
on yt.id_tracking=mt.idt
where mt.idt is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do like this:

- Do you have a different table for tracking IDs i.e. ID_tracking? If yes, then add a **does_it_have_action** column there to check if tracking ID has a action added in actions table.
- When a new entry is added to your table with ID_tracking and ID_action then update that tracking IDs table and set **does_it_have_action = 1** else keep it default 0.
- When you want to check the tracking IDs for actions, just make a select query to this table.

Now, you will have to care about update and insert statements to this tracking IDs table. So, whenever an action is added for a tracking ID, check this tracking IDs table if ID_tracking exists or not. If exists then update does_it_have_action column equals to 1 else insert it with does_it_have_action = 0.

I hope that will work for you **when you will have billions of rows one day.**

P.S: Here is a rough structure for this new table tracking_ids

> ID_tracking | does_it_have_action (default to 0) | created_at (current
>   timestamp)

Comment: that is just a portion of the table, adding does_it_have action is not an option, i need to find a fast working query to do what i need.

Comment: Then go for testing the posted solutions. They seem to be OK. You can use "explain" keyword before the select query to see the performance of select query and things fetched/used in the query.